# PHP Newsletter System

Tags: php, email, newsletter

I need to create a PHP Newsletter System which detects when an e-mail is read, forwarded, printed and deleted. The response is then caught and inserted in a database.

How should I approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: Start with sending e-mails, go from there ;)

Comment: Emails (as in regular email, as provided by gmail for instance) gives you no way to really detect if the email was read, forwarded, or printed. There are ways to embed an image link and then monitor how many times the image is requested to get an idea of how many times the email is viewed, but what you're describing isn't possible.

Comment: In addition to @WesleyvanOpdorp: Start reading about how emails and the whole things work, and then go from there ;)

Answer (score 1):

The only feedback you can get are from pictures loaded by the email client (often called *beacon*), which can only tell you that this particular client loaded that picture. Some person won't load the images although they read the e-mail, and you cannot do anything about forwarding, printing or deletion afaik.

> **In email**
>
> Web bugs are frequently used in spamming (sending unsolicited commercial email) as a way of "pinging" to find which spam recipients open (and presumably read) before deleting it.
>
> Tracking in email can be disabled by:
>
> - Many web bugs can be avoided by turning off HTML display and displaying only the text.
> - Turning off the display of images while still using HTML may still allow other techniques to be used.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_bug#In_email